# Publish Application in azure unable to create token when signin

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, office365, azure-web-app-service

I run the [O365-ASPNETMVC-Start](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start) in local host (https://localhost:44300/) its working fine everything . When i publish code in azure website we are facing problems.

1.**Signin issue**--> Open the URL and after sign in click any link like Email it showing error message 
but it working fine in localhost. What we observed in localhost When sign in enter credentials click signin button one **ADALTokenCache** row inserted into database (**ADALTokenCacheDb**) but not inserted any row when published url signin. After i tried different way through localhost i pointed to ServerDB and tried to signin now ADALTokenCache row inserted in serverdb working fine click Emil anything. after tried published URL with same MailID its working fine. So each emailID first time only problem, once record inserted after working fine. What is the problem.

2. **Signout issue**--> Localhost its redirect to home page and display sign in button but in published code redirect to home page with username and signout buttons. what is the problem.

Can you please help me any permissions are required, i tried different ways but .no use.

Thanks

Hemanth

Answer (score 0):

@hmk,
Seems that the code sample needs the local DB. As far as I known, we can't run the SQL Server/SQL Express on the Azure Web Apps server. Could you please double check  `ConnectionString` on web.Config file? If your DB is on Azure SQL Database, please make sure you have added your Web Apps IP address into the "Allowed List"(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/)

Comment: Hi will Shao, Thanks for reply. I done that part before publish only